# Changing the request URL before request getting matched with the location or server

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, lua, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm using k8s cluster with nginx-ingress controller. I have a requirement to add a text to request URL before the request matches with server and location.

Ex: Request: abc.com/access/endpoint

I have an ingress that has host as abc.com and path as /access/(*.). So when the request is made the request matches with the ingress and directs the request to the service endpoint as expected.

But what I need is to change the request to abc.com/access/newtext/endpoint and then make it available for ingress. Is it possible to achieve this?

Thanks on advance

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it, but would the `rewrite` annotation help you?

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#rewrite

> In some scenarios the exposed URL in the backend service differs from the specified path in the Ingress rule. Without a rewrite any request will return 404. Set the annotation nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target to the path expected by the service.

> If the Application Root is exposed in a different path and needs to be redirected, set the annotation nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root to redirect requests for /.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the issue is the URL rewrite logic is a bit complex. It involves some processing. So we cannot hardcode that need a bit of scripting

Comment: Then perhaps it may be worth using an ingress to an apache service, do the rewrite in there, then use your other service as the backend for that? It's a bit convoluted: request -> ingress -> apache -> service, but it should work, we do something similar with the apache service handling some redirects, before offloading any remaining requests to the backend service